# Error with: "brew install --cask basictex"

Tags: installing, mac

**How to solve this error, when typing "brew install --cask basictex" from a Mac's terminal?**

**Input**

```
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$ brew install --cask basictex
```

**Output (including the Error):**

```
==> Caveats
You must restart your terminal window for the installation of MacTex CLI tools to take effect.
Alternatively, Bash and Zsh users can run the command:

  eval "$(/usr/libexec/path_helper)"

==> Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-202103
==> Downloading from https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-bas
#=#=#                                                                         
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
Error: Download failed on Cask 'basictex' with message: Download failed: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-20210325.pkg
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$
```

Comment: Exactly what is it trying to download with `Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-202103` is something cut of here? That URL does not exist. Any specific reason you don't just install MacTeX as it is probably the easiest LaTeX to install.

Comment: Thanks @daleif, I think I have solved it by typing (1) ```brew update``` (2) ```brew upgrade```, and (3) ```brew install --cask mactex```, exactly in this order, in my terminal :)

Comment: I'm still a bit weary about what brew actually installs. There is some system for mac who ends up installing a version that cannot be updated using the normal tlmgr.

Comment: I would recommend not using `homebrew` to install MacTeX. And I don't recommend installing BasicTeX if you are a beginner. Install the full MacTeX package from here: https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Comment: @daleif I think `homebrew` actually just uses the MacTeX installer, but it's really not worth doing it through `homebrew` and (as we can see) more likely to lead to problems.

Comment: @AlanMunn exactly my worries

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! Thanks @AlanMunn, I followed your instructions in this order, (1) ```brew uninstall mactex```, (2) download ```MacTeX.pkg``` from [MacTex website](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and it works!